# spring property placeholder with custom prefix in resource attribute of import element

Tags: java, spring

I need to be able to say `<import resource="context-@{subname}.xml" />`. Can I do it with Spring 3.1.2.

Comment: I doubt you can do that with Spring. What's 'subname' coming from? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Giodude - I am trying to make relatively bulky parts of context changeable via a single configuration property visible to the application user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could certainly use SpEL to pull in your "subname" from, for example, your environment:

```
<import resource="context-#{environment['subname']?:'somedefault'}.xml" />
```

However, if you're doing that, you should probably be pulling all of your settings in from your environment (System Properties and System Environment) instead, but if you really need to do different xml files based on environment, perhaps you should instead take a look Spring's Profiles to separate your configurations into logical groups:

http://java.dzone.com/articles/using-spring-profiles-xml